# Sorting list of pair

Tags: c++

Why is this code not compiling?

I am trying to sort list by `int` value, its complaining about `operator -`

```
int main() {
    list<pair<string, int> > expired;

    sort(expired.begin(), expired.end(), [](const pair<string, int> & left, const pair<string, int> & right) { return left.second < right.second; });
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe an iterator problem. Binary sort would need a random access iterator but std::list does not offer it. Hence, the ``operator-()`` is not supported by ``std::list::iterator`` type. ``std::list`` has a "BidirectionalIterator".

Comment: In cases when code does not compile, compiler emits error messages. You should carefully read all of them. If you don't understand the error messages, you should look up the compiler's documentation. If you don't understand the compiler's documentation, you should perform a serch on the web. Only after all this research, if you found nothing that solves your problem, you should ask for someone's help. In this case, you should include exact error messages into your question.

Comment: yep , i solved it, list does not have random access, i had to use functor and then pass it to list.sort()